# Map Floppy A drive to USB

Tags: windows, usb, mappeddrive, floppy

I need a way to assign my windows A: drive to a usb. In fact multiple usb's keys and always the standard windows floppy drive A:. It doesn't need to be bootable...

Yes I know that I can set the drive letter but this is not persistant. 
If I change the USB key the new one is drive letter E:\ again...

I have 3 USB keys that rotate so everytime I take one of the keys it should appear as drive letter A:
I should not be limited to 1.44 MB

I know there is a key from hp which has some sort of bios on it. But that is also not what would help me... Just general USB keys.

Is there a tool or a service or an emulator which runs in the background that's maps any usb drive to A:

Any help would be great thanks..

Comment: Assuming this were possible, what would happen if two USB sticks were plugged in at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this tool useful it is called USB Drive letter manager...
http://www.uwe-sieber.de/usbdlm.html

Answer (score 1):

Even though you said it doesn't need to be bootable... here's the way to make it bootable so it will come up at an A:\ prompt:

http://elnexus.com/articles/floppy-vista.aspx

UPDATE:

If you're using Windows XP try this:

1. Click the Windows Start Button.
2. Click Control Panel
3. Click Performance and Maintinance
4. Click Administrative Tools
5. Double Click Computer Managment
6. Click on Disk Managment
7. At the Bottom of that screen, right click on the drive that you want to assign a letter to, and select Change Drive Letter.
8. Click on the Drive that you are assigning in the pop up dialog.
9. Click Change
10. In The drop down box that is shown, select the letter that you would like assigned
11. Click on okay.

This will reassign the drive letter for your drive.

When you plug/unplug the drives they should come up with the same drive letters.

The only thing I DON'T know sure sure is if "A:" will work or not.

Comment: using windows xp

Comment: this does not work since I have a rotation of 3 usb sticks. If it were one it would be a solution... but this is what I had already tried... =(

Answer (score 1):

No that I know of, the drive letter mapping is usually stored with the drive id, as is any NTFS folder mount.

Answer (score 1):

Note that I would try all other options first. There is a utility that has been around since the beginning of time called [SUBST](http://www.ss64.com/nt/subst.html) that will map any drive path to a drive letter.

With this you could run the SUBST command (below) directly or through a batch file, automatically with an [Autorun.inf](http://dailycupoftech.com/usb-drive-autoruninf-tweaking/) file when you plug the drive in.

```
SUBST A: %~dp0
```

If you are using XP, you might also want to look at [Microsoft USB Flash Drive Manager](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=94991901-bfc4-485e-bcae-c9df0accdaae).

Answer (score 0):

What about a [Virtual floppy drive](http://www.pendriveapps.com/virtual-floppy-drive/) *on* a USB stick?

Comment: Looks like you have to specify like 1.44 MB for a virtual floppy. I need way more memory =(

Answer (score 0):

If drive letter is always E have a look at subst command. Complete help can be found using

```
subst /?
```